# Extending a dict: Passing keyword args via a through function does not work

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am trying to extend a dict using

> dict(existing, **kwargs)

But this does not work when the *kwargs* are coming via another function. 
Can someone help me understand why is this so?

Sample test code:

```
def funct(*args, **kwargs):
    a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    print kwargs
    return dict(a, **kwargs)

def thrgh(*v, **var):
    print var
    funct(*v, **var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'hello world'
    print funct(c=3)
    print 'helloWorld-thrg'
    print thrgh(c=3)
```

Output

```
hello world
{'c': 3}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
helloWorld-thrg
{'c': 3}
{'c': 3}
None
```

Comment: in `thrgh` you should `return funct(*v, **var)`.

Comment: That's right! Missed something fundamental. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You just need this:

```
def funct(*args, **kwargs):
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print (args)
print (kwargs)    
return dict(a, **kwargs)

funct('t', c=1)
```

---

This will return:

```
('t',)
{'c': 1}

{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```

Comment: Actually it was a missing `return`. Ref to @hiro's comment